# Unreal Engine 4: Help with multithreading and accessing render target images

Tags: multithreading, unreal-4, rendertargets

I am working on an application where I need to record images seen from an in-game camera. Initially, the method was to set up a TextureRenderTargetResource from the in-game capture component, and subsequently call ReadPixels to access the frame data and save that data as an image. (code flow below)

```
bool saveImage() {
  USceneCaptureComponent2D* capture = getCaptureComponent(camera_type, true);
  FTextureRenderTargetResource* RenderResource = capture->TextureTarget->GameThread_GetRenderTargetResource();
  width = capture->TextureTarget->GetSurfaceWidth();
  height = capture->TextureTarget->GetSurfaceHeight();

  TArray<FColor> imageColor;
  imageColor.AddUninitialized(width * height);
  RenderResource->ReadPixels(bmp);
}
```

This approach was slowing the game thread down significantly, so I am trying to move the screenshot saving procedure to its own thread. My approach now is inspired by the article at https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Multi-Threading:_How_to_Create_Threads_in_UE4. I access the *AActor object from this separate thread and subsequently its camera, and then I call the saveImage() function from the thread: but this is resulting in a crash with no additional information (just "*UE4Editor.exe has triggered an exception*") at the call to ReadPixels(). So essentially, calling saveImage() and thereby ReadPixels() from the game thread works perfectly, and it fails when I call it from a different thread. Am I doing something wrong in my process here?

Comment: This feels like an access issue, like the camera is thread-locked somehow. As far as the crash, connect VS to unreal while the game is running and you may get a better trace - if not, grab the source from GitHub and try again.

Comment: I ended up fixing it: the native implementation of ReadPixels has a call to a function FlushRenderingCommands (), which should only be called from the game thread. I had to rewrite the ReadPixels functionality in my own thread to solve this particular problem.